# Facebook Workplace Integration with OAuth flow

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, integration, facebook-workplace

I am working on a web app, in which I want to fetch the feed (posts) of a `Facebook-Workplace` Group,

On https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ When I tried to create a new app, I was unable to select the Workplace as a product in the app.

So currently, I am accessing the API by `Access-Token` generating from Custom Integration. I used the following steps to generate token:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/integrations/custom-integrations/apps/

```
- In the Admin Panel, open the Integrations tab.
- Click on the Create App button.
- Choose a relevant name and description for the app.
- Choose the required permissions for the app, based on the integration functionality you require.
- Copy and safely store the access token that's shown to you. You'll need this when making API calls.
```

It is working well. But I want to call the APIs by `Access-Token` provided by `OAuth` flow, to make it secure because if the Access-Token is captured by someone, then anyone can call the APIs,

I also checked that there is an option in App's Security Settings **Require App Secret Proof**, but still have doubt,

[image]

So please help me, if can call `Facebook-Workplace` APIs by OAuth flow,
Any suggestions are helpful

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: I integrated with the same steps, which I mentioned, no Oauth is available for workplace APIs

Comment: I more thing, is facebook login is necessary for facebook-workplace integration?
I want to create a post from my website to facebook workplace

Comment: No, facebook login is not required for facebook-workplace integration